# jquery load closest question

Tags: jquery

I want to load a particular link when user press link.

**jQuery:**

```
<body>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(".likeThis").click(function() {
      jQuery(this).closest("a").load('{$likeThiSID}', function() {
    });
  });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<span id="like"><a class="likeThis">Like This</a>
```

I am using CMS and that HTML code is echoed in a while where there will be around 10 entries.

Right now jQuery is working but it's loading 10 times. How do I get which one of the link is clicked?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you meant when you say "echoing 10 times", because I don't see where the echo code is - is it the `.load` function running 10 times, or is it some server-side code that's running 10 times?

Comment: oh, i mean load running 10 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(".likeThis").not('.bound').click(function() {     
  jQuery(this).closest("a").load('{$likeThiSID}', function() {
}).addClass('bound');

</script>
```

It only binds the click to elements that does'nt have a class "bound". As after binding the elements will receive this class, they'll not be affected later.

Another way may be gone with different markup :

```
<span id="like"><a class="likeThis" href="{$likeThiSID}">Like This</a>
```

(assuming that {$likeThiSID} will be replaced with a URL)

By that you dont need the script-part inside the loop, you'll only need

```
jQuery(document).ready(
  function(){jQuery(".likeThis").click(
    function()
    {
      jQuery(this).load(this.href,function(){});
      return false;
    }
   )
  }
);
```

...once inside the document.